# Issue with requiring of nodemailer in React.js;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email after registration to a user. But I am having an issue with requiring of nodemailer module. I am getting the following error:

[image]

-The version of my npm is: 6.2.0

-The version of my node is: v8.11.1

-My package.json looks like this:

[image]

-My function for sending email looks like this:

```
sendEmail() {

         var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


         nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {

             let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                 host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                 port: 587,
                 secure: false,
                 auth: {
                     user: 'example@gmail.com',
                     pass: 'example'
                 }
             });

             let mailOptions = {
                 from: '"Example" <example@gmail.com>',
                 to: this.inputEmail.value,
                 subject: 'Successful registration!',
                 text: "Thank you registing with us!"
             };

             transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                 if (error) {
                     return console.log(error);
                 }

                 console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
                 console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
             })
         })

     }
```

Comment: Isn't nodemailer a Node.js library? I don't think you can use it in the browser.

Comment: Aha, how should I use it?

Comment: E.g. create a new route in your backend that you call from your frontend, that in turn sends an email.